# Puppeteer: How to get DOM after switching chromium Tabs?

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

Right now I am getting all the DOM from Only one Tab which is Default.But I want to capture DOM from Each tab after Switching.

Here is the my sample code.

```js
async function RedirectToLogin(page)
{

console.log(page.content());

}

async function main() {
    const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: false});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
 await page.setViewport({
    width: 2000,
    height: 1000,
  });

  await page.goto('https://www.google.com/');
  console.log('clicked');
  browser.on('targetchanged', () => RedirectToLogin(page));
count++;
}

main();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the URL for the currently active page by doing the following:

```
const url = await page.url();
console.log(url);
```

Comment: Thanks @AJC24. If I have multiple Tabs If I changed to other Tab How Can I get that updated Active Tab.

Comment: If you change to another tab you should be able to just re-run that piece of code, above, and it will get the URL for that tab. `page.url()` returns the URL for the currently active page in the browser.